# Single layout for 'edit' and 'debug' in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2008, 'Start Debugging' switches Visual Studio to a different layout.  How can I force Visual Studio to use a single layout at all times?

I could attempt to lay out my windows in both normal and 'Debug' modes as similarly as possible.  However, i) Visual Studio will still do a visible redraw, and ii) I have to keep the layouts in sync manually.

Update:  It seems the correct terms are 'Design View' and 'Debugging View'.  According to [Window Layouts: The Four Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/zainnab/window-layouts-the-four-modes) 'There is no way to tell Visual Studio to use one state for all modes at this time.'  Is this really true?

Comment: the years pass and I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 is something has changed in this situation? There is solution for  haveing the same window arrangement for all VS states? (mainly for edit and debug)

Comment: While this is still true, note [Primc- export and edit layout xml to have identical design/debug views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445687/199364). Also there is now hot key support to switch between layouts: [Microsoft- Customize window layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The [website you found](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/21/window-layouts-the-four-modes-vstipenv0051.aspx) is indeed accurate:

> There are four different window layout modes in Visual Studio:
>
> - *Design View* - this is the one you see when you start up Visual Studio. It's what most people refer to as the "normal" view.
> - *Debugging View* - this is the view that you get when you enter Debug Mode like when you are stepping through your code
> - *Full Screen* - the view you get when you go to View -> Full Screen (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
> - *File View* - the lesser known view you can get when you open up a file in DevEnv.eve
>
> The thing to remember here is that, both, your tool windows and your command bar customizations are saved separately for each state.  There is no way to tell Visual Studio to use one state for all modes at this time.  Additionally, when you shut down Visual Studio in any state, all four states are saved.

It's very strange that you would want to use the same window layout for all four modes. The same windows that are useful at design time are hardly ever useful during debugging, and vice versa.
For example, in Debugging View, I hide the Toolbox, Document Outline, and Property Manager windows. Then, I add the immensely useful Call Stack, Autos, Locals, Processes, Modules, and Breakpoints windows. None of the latter panes would be remotely useful to me in design mode, so I don't want them taking up screen space. But they're *invaluable* in debug mode, so I want them to show up. I also resize windows in the two different modes, based on their *relative* importance (such as the Properties window).

If you really still think that the two views should have the same window layout, the best you can do is rearrange the windows manually to achieve the same layout in both modes. I also recommend exporting your Window Layout settings (Tools -> Import and Export Settings) so that you have a fresh copy to revert back to in the case of disaster. I keep settings files containing my preferred window layout settings for single monitor (laptop), dual monitor, and triple monitor configurations.

Comment: No doubt multiple layouts are great.  Ideally I would like to switch between these with a hot key.  If I recall rightly, Eclipse allows me to switch layout manually.  I forget whether it is possible in Eclipse to disable this auto-switching behaviour.

Comment: @Crosbie: No, VS doesn't support hotkeys to switch between window layouts either. I honestly can't say I've ever wanted that feature. I like everything to be in the same place so that I can find it. You might try the automatic docking behavior of windows (click the pushpin icon), which will cause them to move out of the way unless you're using them. That seems like the best replacement for hotkey switching.

Comment: I for one would love to be able to set up my own layouts, then manually say 'use this one for design and use this one for debug', etc.  That way, I, not VS, decides what goes where.  Plus, that would allow me to easily say 'Copy this one to another' which I could then simply tweak, rather than having to manually reposition everything to make them all match up.  I think MS dropped the ball here.  Something like what I described would suit everyone.  Those who want separate can still have them just as today, but those that want a single one, or better yet, more than one per, can have that too.

Comment: @MarquelV: You can already do the first thing you requested. VS supports different layouts for design mode, debug mode, etc. *You*, not VS, *already* decide what goes where. The only thing that's missing is the ability to copy settings from one mode to the other. I'm not really sure that's a huge omission. Lay out the windows the way you want to once, and your settings are saved and remembered. You can even export them to another machine for convenience. I keep my Solution Explorer in relatively the same place for design and debug mode. I'm not going to lose control if it's 10 pixels off.

Comment: @Cody Gray: That's incorrect, Visual Studio supports hotkey switching between settings. It requires substantial effort but once setup it works very well. I will answer and elaborate

Comment: @Chris: That's a nice answer, and it gets a +1 from me because you took the time to write it all out. But technically, you've written a custom macro, which isn't really using functionality built into Visual Studio. The fact that the IDE is highly extensible *is* a very important feature, so you can pretty much do anything you want with a macro. That doesn't mean the IDE itself supports hotkey switching. (And more to the point, it doesn't solve the problem in the original question. I'd have proposed a macro-based solution had one been asked for when I took the time to write my answer.)

Comment: Personally I concur with the question poster. I find it very annoying that there are two modes. Yes, there are different sets of windows between debug and design, but I typically have all those in one place - call stack, threads and immediate go in the same location as build output etc. And the basic layout, with solution explorer, team explorer, navigation windows etc. I want in one place all the time.

Comment: the years pass and I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 is something has changed in this situation? There is solution for haveing the same window arrangement for all VS states? (mainly for edit and debug)

Comment: No, no changes have been made to this model in current versions of Visual Studio so far as I'm aware, @szkut. I also use VS 2017 daily.

Comment: My projects has a huge amount of templates and/or overloads, so finding the right function call sites is not easy in "design mode". I regularly do breakpoints and "find all"s in debug mode running the process, and when I have found the right entry point, I need to kill the process and make changes and build and rerun. It really annoys me if the "find all references" view hides when it returns to design mode.

Comment: @CodyGray The reason to have the same layout for design and debug is muscle memory. Things flapping around when modes are changed is hardly useful to keep you focused. Unused call stack or threads or memory windows from debug layout do not waste any extra space in design layout since they are all tabs. I guess it all depends on how you split your windows and how many monitors you use, but I don't think it is unreasonable to want the same layout for all modes.

Answer (score 20):

As others have pointed out, you can't use one settings group to control both design and debug views.  Visual Studio doesn't make it easy to get the most out of window placement settings, but the approach I use to manage layouts might help.

Instead of frequently adjusting window placements by hand, try to think of a fixed number of different views you want to work with.  Eclipse has perspectives, window layouts you can switch between.  Think of Visual Studio this way.  For example, I use two layouts in Visual Studio:  one to take advantage of two monitors when I'm sitting at my physical workstation, another for one monitor when I'm working remotely.  If you can constrain yourself to using a group of layouts that makes sense for you without manually adjusting windows, you can make design and debug window placements the same for each layout.

However, switching between layouts is painful with Visual Studio out of the box.  You have to go to Tools->Import and Export Settings and select the layout manually.  It takes more than five mouse clicks and sometimes 15 seconds to switch layouts this way on my workstation.  We can do much better!

1. Save the window positions you want for each layout to settings files
2. Make a macro to load each settings file
3. Bind the macros to keyboard shortcuts or toolbar buttons

**Save window positions to a settings file**

Arrange windows the way you want them for a specific layout.  Visual Studio saves the location for nearly every window (e.g. Solution Explorer, Output, Find and Replace), so be thorough.  Visual Studio saves design and debug layouts in a single file so arrange windows in both views.

Go to Tools->Import and Export Settings. Choose Export selected environment settings and click Next.
The next dialog prompts you to select the settings to export.  Uncheck all settings except General Settings/Window Layouts so only window placements are saved, like in these screen shots (I can't expand the window so here are two shots of the same dialog):

[image: Choose settings to export]

[image: Choose settings to export]

Enter a name for this settings file and save it.  Repeat until you have a settings file for each layout.  There is no limit to how many settings files you may have.

**Make a macro to load each settings file**

Go to Tools->Macros->Macro Explorer to show your macros.  There should already be a macro project named MyMacros.  Create an empty macro project if none are visible.  Double click any module in any of these projects to open up the macro editor.

Enter this into the editor.  You want one main sub that takes a path to a settings file and loads the file, and one sub for each individual file that calls the main sub.  If you save your settings files to the same folder you can have the per-file subs pass just the file name instead of the whole path.

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module Module1

    Private RootFolder As String = "C:\Path\To\Folder\With\Settings\Files\"

    Private Sub ImportSettingsFile(ByVal FileName As String)
        FileName = IO.Path.Combine(RootFolder, FileName & ".vssettings")
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "-import:""" & FileName & """")
    End Sub

    'Corresponds to file layoutA.settings    
    Public Sub ImportLayoutA()
        ImportSettingsFile("layoutA")
    End Sub

    'Corresponds to file layoutB.settings
    Public Sub ImportLayoutB()
        ImportSettingsFile("layoutB")
    End Sub

    'Repeat for each settings file

End Module
```

Close the macro editor and go back to Visual Studio.  You're done!  Running any of these macros will load the settings files automatically.  You can double click any of the subs in Macro Explorer to run them.  If you display Macro Explorer at all times this might be sufficient, but if you don't or would rather not have to click the macros to run them we can do even better ...

**Bind the macros to keyboard shortcuts or toolbar buttons**

Go to Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard.  This window allows you to change any keyboard bindings.   Type "Macro" without quotes into the Show commands containing text box.  This will show the macros you created.  Select any macro, click in the text box titled Press shortcut keys, and enter the keyboard shortcut you want to use to run the macro.  Hit Assign, then OK.  You can now use this keyboard command to load the settings file.

[image]

Alternately, you can use a toolbar button instead of or in addition to a keyboard binding.  Go to Tools->Customize.  Select the Commands tab, select Toolbar, and select the toolbar you want to add the button to (Standard is the main toolbar).  Click Add Command, select the Macros category, select the macro you want to add a button for, and click OK.  You will have a new button on the toolbar that loads the window layout from that macro.

[image]

[image]

Keep in mind that keyboard shortcuts and toolbar buttons are themselves settings.  If you import a settings file that overwrites either of them you will have to redo this last step.  The window placement settings files won't overwrite these values because you only exported window locations.  It's a good idea to periodically export and back up all settings, not just window settings, in case something like this happens and you want to recover non-window settings.

Comment: Macros don't exist anymore, so anything related to macros won't work.  FYI.

Answer (score 5):

I think your question was, "How do I use the same settings for both modes?" Am I right? Although @Chris gave an excellent thesis on how to stuff automagically, I wanted to point out, for anyone else that finds this question that there is an easy way to acheive same window settings for both design and debug modes.

Export your settings:

1. Choose General Settings/Window Layouts (in VS 2013) and save the file.
2. Open the file in an XML editor (or whatever... it's an XML file)
3. Find /UserSettings/Category/Design/WindowProfile and copy the entire node. 
   -- This assumes your Design view is the one you want to use for both modes.
4. Find /UserSettings/Category/Debug/WindowProfile and replace it with the one you copied from Design.
5. Save and re-import.

I have one of these settings files for home, remote, and office.

Answer (score 1):

Many people try to turn off this feature because of strange behaviors (glitches) of VS windows on multi-monitor configurations.

In such cases there is another option that can help:
Turn off Environment->General->"Optimize rendering for screens with different pixels densities"

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/830128/windows-layout-not-restoring-properly-in-multi-mon.html